# Crosstabs - combine info of rows into columns

Tags: r, crosstab

I will give an example of my problem since I don't know exactly how to name it, I guess there is probably allready a topic on this.
This is the old situation, I have this table:

```
- a b c
1 0.5 0.3 0.2
2 0.4 0.6 0.5
```

And this is the table I would like:

```
a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
0.5 0.4 0.3 0.6 0.2 0.5
```

How can I best manage this? It is a large dataset ~ 13000 obs. of 11 variables for 42 excelfiles. This is what I thusfar got:

```
# convert to date if not already
weatherdata..5341$Date <- as.Date(weatherdata..5341$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
# get months
weatherdata..5341$Month <- months(weatherdata..5341$Date)
# take average of a column per month
average <- ddply(weatherdata..5341, c("Month"), function(x) colMeans(x[c("Max.Temperature", "Min.Temperature","Precipitation", "Wind", "Relative.Humidity", "Solar")]))
```

Any input is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unlist` to create a `vector`

```
v1 <- unlist(df1)
v1
# a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2 
#0.5 0.4 0.3 0.6 0.2 0.5
```

If this needs to be converted to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame.list(v1)
#   a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2
#1 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.6 0.2 0.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(0.5, 0.4), b = c(0.3, 0.6), c = c(0.2, 0.5
)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2"))
```